# Required Field that is Uneditable in Form

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am having an issue with a form having a required field that is uneditable. It results in an error when you try and save it.

[image]

The Title field is editable, however the Subject field is not.

This only seems to be happening for some users, ones with admin rights have no problems editing the subject field. I checked the permissions for articles and everything is enabled for all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the *Append To* privilege is enabled on the *Subject* on the roles you want to allow this behavior.

[image]